# Image is not displaying in Form2

Tags: c#

I'm trying to display theimage in form2 at particular time period.The list box have 10 images(Shown below).Image is not displaying in form2 Why?

```
list box is like
   1.C:\\image1 ,2(sec),3(sec)  -----2sec-displaying the image1 ,3sec Displaying the blank image
   2.C:\\image2 ,3(sec),1(sec)
   3.C:\\image3 ,1(sec),2(sec)
     upto 10 image
```

Form1.cs

```
private void Showbtn_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
   {
     int i=0;
     while(i<listbox.items.count)
       {
          string strpath=listbox1.items[i].Tostring();
          string[] str1= strpth.Split(',');
          f2.updateimage(str1[0]);
          f2.show();
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((Convert.Toint32(str1[1]))*1000);
          String Blankimage=@"C://Blankimage.bmp";        
          f2.updateimage(Blankimage) ;
          f2.Show();
          System.Threading.thread.Sleep(Convert.Toint32(str1[2]) * 1000); 
          i++;
         }
    }
```

Form2.cs

```
 public updateimage(string imgpath)
   {
       picturebox1.Load(imgpath);
    }
```

Error

```
  imageDisplay.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows       \Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Symbols loaded.
'imagedisplay.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll', Symbols loaded.
   thread '<No name>' (0x02fc) has exited with code 0
```

Comment: have you tried debugging your code ?

Comment: yes, i getting error like  thread <no name> (0xd2c>) has exited with code 0..

Comment: I think you should pas the list to the constructor of form 2 and then start a background thread to do the job, I faced a similar problem and then [Threading](http://www.dotnetperls.com/thread) solved my problem.

Comment: You should also have posted the error message then..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the main thread is busy by your while loop, so we asking it to update the form2 object to draw it again

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        f2.Show();
        while (i < listBox1.Items.Count)
        {
            string strpath = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
            string[] str1 = strpath.Split(',');
            f2.updateimage(str1[0]);
            f2.Update();// Add This Line to make the second form update it self
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            String Blankimage = @"C://Blankimage.bmp";     
            f2.updateimage(Blankimage);
            f2.Update(); // Add This Line to make the second form update it self
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it  showing error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

You have to let your main UI to update your form while sleeping (like refreshing images). For this to be done, you can "async wait" instead of blocking your main thread with a Thread.Sleep :

```
private async void Showbtn_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    int i=0;
    while(i<listbox.items.count)
    {
        string strpath=listbox1.items[i].Tostring();
        string[] str1= strpth.Split(',');
        f2.updateimage(str1[0]);
        f2.show();
        await Task.Delay(Convert.Toint32(str1[1]));
        String Blankimage=@"C://Blankimage.bmp";        
        f2.updateimage(Blankimage) ;
        //f2.Show(); => You don't need that line
        await Task.Delay(Convert.Toint32(str1[2]));
        i++;
    }
}
```